# Is there a translator from Haskell to Coq?

Tags: haskell, coq

If I want to write proofs and algorithms/semantics using Coq on a Haskell program. How can I translate from Haskell to Coq to do this?

It seems that there are tools to translate OCaml programs. But how about Haskell?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: you can definitely go [the other direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334863/can-i-extract-a-coq-proof-as-a-haskell-function).

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but you might also be interested in HERMIT. It is a toolkit for proving theorems about Haskell code (among other things). If you do decide to check it out I would suggest looking at HERMIT-shell, which is the new (and currently under active development) shell for the system. Full disclosure: I work on HERMIT and HERMIT-shell as part of my job.

Comment: @DavidYoung Can HERMIT help to prove arbitrary property or just optimized code equivalence? The short introduction seems to indicate the latter one.

Comment: @xywang You can use it to prove properties of a Haskell program, too. There are examples of this in the examples/laws directory. Here is the HERMIT-shell version: https://github.com/ku-fpg/hermit-shell/tree/master/examples/laws. The Haskell file "under scrutiny" here is `ListLaws.hs` and the other files are HERMIT-shell script files (also written in Haskell, using the HERMIT-shell DSL) that prove theorems about the code in the `ListLaws.hs` file. The GHC `RULES` get turned into lemmas, which can then be proven.

Comment: [coq-haskell](https://github.com/jwiegley/coq-haskell) might also be relevant

Comment: Perhaps this belongs at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com - New info about it though, Antal Spector-Zabusky posted software project [hs-to-coq](https://github.com/antalsz/ha-to-coq) "in fairly good shape", funded under a grant NSF 1521602 ["DeepSpec"](http://DeepSpec.org) with principal investigator Andrew Appel at Princeton University.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue I see in such a translation is that Haskell programs (as well as Ocaml ones) can perform any kind of recursion algorithm, and might contain loops.

In Coq, there is no build-in notion of loops, and any recursive function *has* to terminate, and be explicit why it terminates.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such tool at the moment.

Comment: There is a paper that describes a method for [converting "total functional programs"](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~criz/publications/hs_to_coq.pdf) from Haskell into Coq.